# Determining how many miles can be covered on full tank

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank

I'm interested in the following cars, but the questions apply equally well to any car:

- Audi TT
- Lexus IS 200 (SE or not?)

I'm finding it difficult to determine the following:

1. How do I figure out how much fuel a particular car can hold?
2. How do I figure out how much a fuel tank will cost (in the UK)?  A website of some sort?
3. So from the above I can sort of figure out how much a fulltank will last me in terms of miles.  So if I know much fuel the tank can hold, and I know the cost of the fuel tank, and I know how mpg the car does I can work out what the cost of fuel would cost me.  Am I missing something.

I mention `figure` because I'd like to see the steps taken to arrive at the value.

Thank you and I appreciate all the help or insight you can offer.

Answer (score 3):

[www.parkers.co.uk](http://www.parkers.co.uk) gives both fuel tank capacity and manufacturer's quoted mpg for all modern UK-spec cars.

Go to reviews, then the "facts and Figures" page for the model in question.

Fuel prices, as ManiacZS says, can be found from [www.petrolprices.com](http://www.petrolprices.com)

an IS200SE 4-door saloon has a fuel capacity of 70L and a quoted 29mpg, so at current 136.9ppl* you should expect a tank to cost you £95.83 (70 * 136.9 / 100) and last you 447 miles (70L / 4.54 litres in an imperial gallon * 29mpg).

*Which for the Americans on here, is roughly $8.44 per US Gallon.

Answer (score 2):

Edmunds.com has the specifications for most vehicles.

You didn't give a year so I'll do the current 2012 Audi TT Coupe.

1. Go to http://www.edmunds.com
2. In the search box type "2012 Audi TT" and hit enter
3. Choose the coupe model
4. Under available models choose "View All Features & Specs" under the desired model
5. Go to the Fuel section

They list fuel type, grade required, fuel tank capacity, MPG and mile range.

For the 2012 Audi TT Coupe 2.0T AWD
    Fuel type: gas
    Fuel type: premium unleaded (required)
    Fuel tank capacity: 15.9 gal.
    Range in miles (cty/hwy): 365.7/492.9 mi.
    EPA mileage est. (cty/hwy): 23/31 mpg

For fuel prices, in USA and Canada there is http://www.gasbuddy.com, for the UK there is http://www.petrolprices.com  Many others can be found by searching online.

For how to calculate the range yourself, you are right in that you need to know the fuel consumption rate and the size of the tank.

For the Audi TT above having a 15.9 gallon tank and EPA 31 mpg highway you'd do:
15.9 gallons * 31 MPG = 492.9 miles

Answer (score 1):

The size of the tank is usually in the manual, and determining how many miles you can get is trivial. This number will vary in what you are hauling, how you are driving, what speed you are traveling, etc. My Camry can vary from ~24-36 MPG, depending on how I'm driving. Averaging from 350-550 miles to the tank, and the highest usually comes with cruise control on an empty highway.